# What is the“'condition'=>'project_id=:projectId',”？what is the meaning of “：”？

Tags: php, yii

I don’t know What is the“'condition'=>'project_id=:projectId',”？what is the meaning of “：”？ In another word why we should put the “：” in front of the projectId. the code is as below.

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issue',array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'project_id=:projectId',
                'params'=>array(':projectId'=>$this->_project->id),
            ),
        ));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your code snippet, this has to do with escaping query parameters / prepared SQL statements. This prevents SQL injection. In your example, `:projectId` in `condition` is another way of saying "Please replace this `:projectId` with the escaped value of `:projectId` (`$this-_project->id`) from `params` when executing this query".